# Database connection with error in CodeIgniter 2.1.4

Tags: php, database, codeigniter-2

I have this kind of error when I try to install a php scrit make with CodeIgniter 2.1.4

This is the error:

A PHP Error was encountered

```
Severity: 8192
Message: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; CI_DB_driver has a deprecated constructor
Filename: database/DB_driver.php
Line Number: 31
```

This is the code:

```
class CI_DB_driver {

var $username;
var $password;
var $hostname;
var $database;
var $dbdriver       = 'mysql';
var $dbprefix       = '';
var $char_set       = 'utf8';
var $dbcollat       = 'utf8_general_ci';
var $autoinit       = TRUE; // Whether to automatically initialize the DB
var $swap_pre       = '';
var $port           = '';
var $pconnect       = FALSE;
var $conn_id        = FALSE;
var $result_id      = FALSE;
var $db_debug       = FALSE;
var $benchmark      = 0;
var $query_count    = 0;
var $bind_marker    = '?';
var $save_queries   = TRUE;
var $queries        = array();
var $query_times    = array();
var $data_cache     = array();
var $trans_enabled  = TRUE;
var $trans_strict   = TRUE;
var $_trans_depth   = 0;
var $_trans_status  = TRUE; // Used with transactions to determine if a rollback should occur
var $cache_on       = FALSE;
var $cachedir       = '';
var $cache_autodel  = FALSE;
var $CACHE; // The cache class object
```

Comment: What is on line 31?

Comment: I think the issue is you are running a Very Old Codeigniter on a new version of PHP

Comment: Class constructors have been called `__construct()` for a long time now (many versions of PHP)

Comment: And as this code does not show an Old or New version of a contructor, it is probably NOT the script that is actually generating this error

Comment: It's farther down the function, there is an old function called CL_DB_driver and PHP hates that.

Comment: Then you will have to install an older version of PHP. What version are you using